# Learning OpenCMS

Tags: java, jsp, opencms

I am finding for the good resources to learn OpenCMS. Please provide the guideline/best practices to develop an OpenCMS based websites. Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can return do so. I developed certain websites with OpenCMS and I never would choose it as CMS if I had a choice.

Comment: @asrijaal Thanks for the advice. No, I don't have a choice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [wiki](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Main_Page).

There are [books available](http://www.google.ca/search?q=opencms+book). I've only read [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847191053), which was helpful but is targeted more at improving an intermediate skillset rather than being an introduction.

There is also a [mailing list](http://www.opencms.org/en/development/mailinglist.html).

Of course, you can also subscribe to the [Stackoverflow OpenCMS tag feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencms), although it doesn't see a lot of action.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tutorial available. I agree the book is probably best, or study the demo site and it's code that comes with OpenCms. Mailing list is probably only for specific questions, but won't find general introduction material there.

Comment: Thanks Mathias Lin and Cyrena. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, you should IMHO start with creating a simple site. The first thing you need will be a template.

There is a good article in the wiki about that subject:

http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Example_template_with_tree_menu

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime documentation improved a lot and can be found on http://documentation.opencms.org/.